# Is there a reason why adding a value to a column would increase runtime?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a concatenated key from data in each row and then adding it to a dictionary as well as the end column of the row.

For some reason, when just adding to the column or just adding to the dictionary, it works, but when I do both, it takes forever to run. Shouldn't adding a value to the end of a column (in bold below) increase time very marginally?

```
Dim unique_key

Dim sht
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

Dim colNum
colNum = sht.Cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To Rows.Count
    unique_key = Concatenate(CLng(i), id_cols)
    **Cells(CLng(i), colNum).Value = unique_key**

    If dict.Exists(unique_key) Then
        GoTo continue
        Else
        dict.Add unique_key, Cells(i, 10)
    End If
continue:
Next i
```

Comment: would you please show all of your declarations?  `id_cols` doesn't appear to be declared before it's use after `dim colnum`.

Comment: Is this a scenario where you can set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` for the duration of your loop? If so, then combining the two steps shouldn't affect your runtime by any noticeable amount.

Comment: have you tried just using `unique_key = i & id_cols` rather than concatenate and `clng()`?  I can only imagine something is going on with your use of that... please ensure your module indicates `Option Explicit`, and declare `i as long` which should resolve that issue.

Comment: Get rid of the GOTO. Rewrite that to `if not dict.Exists(unique_key) Then dict.Add()`. Another alternative is `if dict.Exists() = False Then`. Either is a vast improvement over GOTO, which is evil. (This doesn't answer your question, it just points out bad practices.)

Comment: @Cyril I actually wrote Concatenate as a function that takes in id_cols which is an array of column numbers of interest and it returns a concatenated string with values from those columns for each row, but it's calculated once for each row whether I choose to add it to the dictionary of add to last column. So i think it shouldn't matter? I'll add the code.

Comment: So... kind of an important question... you use your iterator `i` in your unique key... how would that be repeated ever?  Seems kind of an odd thing to see if the dictionary value exists.  What're you doing wiht the dictionary?

Comment: @taylor, your code loops through every worksheet row (`For i = 2 To Rows.Count`). On top of that, code writes to worksheet per loop iteration, so Excel's probably re-calculating after each write. Might be worth declaring and using some type of `lastRow` variable, so that you only loop over necessary rows -- and setting calculation mode to manual (or use an array) whilst writing. This doesn't explain the increase in time taken.

Answer (score 0):

Going to try and update your code:

```
Option Explicit
Public id_cols 'so you can use it between sub routines

'not sure if the below is part of a function or sub, so not listing

Dim unique_key as string, sht as worksheet, i as long, colNum as long, dict as scripting.dictionary
set dict = NEW scripting.dictionary
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
with sht
colNum = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
    unique_key = i & id_cols
    .Cells(i, colNum).Value = unique_key
    If NOT dict.Exists(unique_key) Then dict(unique_key) = .Cells(i, 10)
Next i
```

Couple things...

- you are wanting to place the value in the last column (colNum) or last column +1?
- what are you doing with the dictionary after it is created?
- Make sure to qualify your references... that would be about the only hiccup i could see in your code

Beyond that, depending on what is in `id_cols` you might have an issue with how the key is being understood.

---

**Edit1:**

Realized i forgot to add what i earlier suggested... `&` not `Concatenate`.  Updated.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but still running forever. This time, I let it run a while and when I force quit it, it gave me an error "method value of object range failed"

Comment: @taylor on the same line?  Sorry, I forgot to put the `&` into my code, just updated.